# Can $‎f(x)=\ln \left\{‎\prod‎_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}\left(\frac{1}{‎(-a^{n+1};a)_x}\right){‎(-a;a)_{‎\infty‎}}^x\right\}‎$ be simpler?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions

Consider ‎the ‎function
‎
$$f(x)=\ln \left\{‎\prod‎‎_{n=1}^{‎\infty‎}\left(\frac{1}{‎(-a^{n+1};a)_x}\right){‎(-a;a)_{‎\infty‎}}^x\right\}$$‎‎
where ‎‎$‎(-a;a)_n‎$ ‎is‎ q-Pochhammer Symbol and $0‎<a‎<1$. Through ‎my ‎research I ‎deal a‎‎ ‎functional ‎sequence ‎that ‎‎$‎‎f$ ‎is ‎its ‎limit function on ‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{R^+}‎$‎. ‎But my ‎question ‎is‎, can ‎$‎‎f$ ‎be ‎simpler?Or Does $f$ have closed form? Thanks.